Can I simplify a linear model output using a chi-square ANOVA interpretation?
I'm wondering if I can simplify a linear model output, for ease of interpretation, using a chi-square ANOVA interpretation. I know this can be done for a logistic regression, but is it appropriate to simplify a linear regression model too (also wondering if it can be done for a binomial regression)?
The code for my model looks like this: model <- lm (response ~ oak + treatment + site, data) (3 species, 4 treatments, 2 sites). I like that the linear model provides the R-square and that I can get emmeans. However, I don't need all the information the model provides for the tests that proceed from it. So I'm wondering if it's acceptable to report the chi-square interpretation of the results that give a p-value for each factor. Code for the ANOVA interpretation is: anova (model, test = "Chisq"). I plan on providing the linear model output table (shown below) in the supplementary section.
If this simplified version is not appropriate, how can I best present the linear model output? I'm a bit confused about it, specifically how the output has a reference variable in each factor. Both output tables (linear model output and of the chi-square output) are attached.
Appreciate any advice.



Ok, so from what I understand now, is that the chi-square interpretation works for any regression model and is explanatory for generic main effect differences but this is not enough to answer the question in full. A pairwise comparisons was recommended to provide a more granular answer. I used the emmeans package to get pairwise comparisons for each of my groups ex:  emmeans(response, pairwise ~ group1)
